# Show that a function is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-sequences

Let $L$ be the space of continuous functions $f(x)$ on $ 0≤x≤1$ and $||f|| = \max|x²f(x)|$, show that the space $L$ is not complete.

I have constructed few sequences of $f_n(x)$ such as $f_n(x) = nx$, when $0≤x≤1/n$, and $f_n(x)=1$ when $1/n≤x≤1$ so that way you get the function within the closed interval $[0,1]$. 
Also, $f_n(x) = x_n$ on $[0,1]$, then $f(x) = 0$, if $x=0$ or $x∈[0,1)$ and $f_n(x) = 1$ if $x=1$. However, after this I need to show that it is a Cauchy sequence in order to prove that the space is incomplete.

How do I prove that this is a Cauchy sequence? Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: To be clear, you would need to show ${f_n}$is a cauchy sequence. Not $x_n$.

Comment: I need to show that fn(x) is a cauchy sequence and also taking into consideration ||f|| whose value is provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)-f_m(x)=0$ if $ n<m$ and $x>\frac 1 n$. For $x \leq \frac  1 n$ we have $| f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \leq |f_n(x)|+|f_m(x)| \leq \frac 2 {n^{2}}$ because $f_n$ and $f_m$ take vales in $[0,1]$. Hence $| f_n(x)-f_m(x)| <\epsilon$ whenever $m>n>n_0$ where $n_0$ is such that $\frac 2 {n_0^{2}} <\epsilon$.

If this Cauchy sequence converges with the given norm then then limit function has to be $0$ at $0$ and $1$ at all other points, a contradiction to continuity. Hence the space is not complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, however I have doubts in this. How did you write |fn(x)-fm(x)| <= |fn(x)|+|fm(x)| ?? As far as i know, it should be <= |fn-f|+|f-fm|. Also, you have to construct f(x) from fn(x) = nx and 0 for those intervals/boundaries. Thanks!!

Comment: $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leqslant |f_n(x)|+|f_m(x)|$ is just the standard triangle inequality on real numbers.

Comment: Ok, thanks!! I wasn't actually familiar with this because I used to follow the previous one which I posted. Anyway, can someone explain how you are getting |fn-fm| as <= 2/n^2. I calculated it, I am getting 1/2n for |fn-f| and 1/2m for |fm-f|.

Comment: @AshisJana Did you notice that $0\leq f_n(x) \leq 1$ for all $n$  and $x$? This implies that $|f_n(x)| \leq x^{2} \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}}$ when $0 \leq x \leq \frac  1 {n^{2}}$. Hence $|f_n(x)|+|f_m(x)| \leq \frac  1 {n^{2}}+\frac  1 {m^{2}}<\frac  2 {n_0^{2}}$.

Comment: Ok got it, I thought about integrating the function fn(x) from 0 to 1/n and from 1/n to 1 and then calculating the value, however that was definitely a wrong approach then. Anyway I got your points now, thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: @AshisJana Would you consider clicking  the tick mark to the left of my answer to approve it?

Comment: Sure, done it. :)